# CiviCRM Export Field to indicate which phone number is being used

Tags: export

I'm trying to create an Export that indicates which phone number (out of Main, Home, Work, Billing, Alternative, etc) is being used for the Primary phone number. Is there a specific field I can include which states which phone number the Primary is using? There's a field called "Phone Type" but that just indicates whether the phone is a landline or mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export that information using the field `Location type` but there seems to be a bug/limitation on the UI. You can indeed find this field for address but not for phone.

As an alternative, you could use Search Kit to get the data you want. You can get a couple of interesting link to get you started on SearchKit here : https://civicrm.org/blog/wmortada/searchkit-new-way-get-data-out-civicrm

When you get there, here is a small example with the field you want :

[image: SearchKit with Phone Location Type]

After saving the Search, you can use View Results and Download as spreadsheet :

[image]

Comment: That's annoying. The version of Civi I'm using doesn't have SearchKit. 

Thanks for confirming I wasn't going mad not being able to find the filed I need.

Comment: It might be easy to fix. Are you able to open an issue in https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues/ ?

Comment: And by the way SearchKit is an extension that is provided with CiviCRM so you might just need to enable it ?